# C# - how to set up vertical scrollbar in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help to make vertical scrollbar work with the panel to scroll down the panel, i tried to make AutoScroll = true but not work, so how I can set yp the vertical scrollbar??
Thanks

Comment: You need to place some controls for example to show the scrollbars(those controls must expand beyhond the panel limit),or set the autoscrollminsize to more then the panel has.

Comment: Have you tried putting anything inside the panel? The scrollbar will only appear once the content of the panel is in excess with its height or width.

Comment: @Saechel i will try it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your panel is named panel1(or else replace it),try the following and you shall see the scrollbars:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Location = new Point(20, panel1.Height + 20);
panel1.Controls.Add(b);
```

I just added a button for demonstration purposes you add whatever you need.
Or as i said in the comments using the autoscrollminsize:

```
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(panel1.Width + 50, panel1.Height + 50);
```